# Error on Running NVIDIA Accelerated Linux Graphics Driver .RUN file

Tags: nvidia

When I try to execute `NVIDIA.run` it is raising the following `ERROR`
I am running `lightdm` server is that one causing problem??
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For reference, see the README provided by Nvidia at http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/295.53/README/installationandconfiguration.html.  Exiting the X server is addressed in the [Before you Begin](http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/295.53/README/installdriver.html#BeforeYouBegin89f39) section.

It depends on what distro you're using, but for example, you can shut down lightdm on Ubuntu using: `sudo /etc/init.d/lightdm stop`.

Unfortunately, installing the Nvidia drivers on Linux is a bit more complicated than it should be, so I would recommend that you have another device handy that you can use to search for solutions to problems you may encounter along the way.  Best of luck.